# getuser function return 0 at first time in browser when facebook login in php sdk suddenly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

At first time when i login to facebook in my browser. i called function getuser for checking purpose but i cant get it it returns zero only. it happened only when i open the browser at first time.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
      'cookie' => true
    ));

$here = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $next = preg_replace('~#.*$~s', '', $here);
    $next = preg_replace('~\?.*$~s', '', $next);
    $next = preg_replace('~/[^/]*$~s', '/login.php', $next);
$params=array(
      'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_birthday,read_stream,read_friendlists,user_about_me,email,user_checkins,friends_checkins,publish_checkins,publish_actions',
      'redirect_uri' => $next
    ); 
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDK stores the facebook user ID and access token in a session, so getUser won't return 0 after auth unless you clear your cookies or re-open your browser like you've done.

You can also call `destroySession()` to remove the cookies in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for reply.please understand my question i need userid only when going to facebook login at first time in any browser but unfortunately it returns zero only instead of userid. so how to fix this issue? it happened only time when browser open at first time